# One static IP for each host in Hyper-V

Tags: networking, hyper-v, vlan

I have dedicated server with Hyper-V server on it. I am creating a 9 guest OS on this server. And they all have to be a different static ip addresses.

But there is a problem. This guests are going to be managed by different users. And this users may try to change ip addresses without asking me.  So i thought i should use vlans to block this option. By doing that, they can only use ip addresses that assigned to that vlan, right?

But, there is a different problem on that. I can't configure my physical switch to assign IP blocks to vlans of this guest machines because I don't have enough IP address. I only have one /28 IP block. So if I try subnetting, it's not going to be enough.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear: you don't have enough external ip addresses? Then you assign addresses from private ip range, and use port forwarding on router to assign different ports on your external address to each of 9 machines port.

You can also change rdp listening port with registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber`

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good, so i am actually having a problem while i want to express myself :)

Comment: I have 9 guest os, on 9 different vlans. They have to be like that. In my cisco switch i can do subneting and assing ip blocks to this vlans. But the problem , i don't have enough ip range to assing.

Comment: @SemihMasat, please add that information to your question so others can find it easily.

Comment: _And this users may try to change ip addresses without asking me. So i thought i should use vlans to block this option._ is this the source of your problem? Would assigning to vlan prevent user from changing the ip address or just block him out if he does? Maybe you have to setup another router(virtual?) between guests and physical router. Awkward, or the whole plan is to be rethought.

Comment: Yes, actually it is. xxx.xxx.xxx.10 is first xxx.12 is for  other guest os. If admin in first os adds xxx.12 to his ip list address. Second guest os is going to be unreachable. Vlans are only first thought. If I can manage this other way, I would prefer that :)